# Error inserting datetime('now') into sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime

I'm trying to create a datetime object that will be easily recognized by SQL when I query it.  I'm creating an initial time stamp, and then reconciling upon this time stamp at future periods.

Here is my code:

```
c.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO aud_qty(pivot_id, '
                                        'folder, '
                                        'order_num, '
                                        'file_name, '
                                        'sent_to_pivot) '
                                        'VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, DATETIME('now'))', 
                                        ((order_n + counter),
                                          cur_dir, 
                                          order_n, 
                                          project_code))
```

I have tried including it in the column after project_code as well, but that doesn't make sense to do since it is a SQL construct, not a Python one.  Thanks!

Comment: You are not escaping your quotes, try `'VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, DATETIME(\'now\'))'` or `"VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, DATETIME('now'))"`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!  Hate those small errors that crop up at 5:00 p.m. when your brain is fried;)